# Sweet Alert not displaying but responsing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

The code below works properly in terms of the AJAX responses. the only problem here is that the `swal` or **Sweet alert** itself is not prompting itself.

```
<script src="../own/sweetalert.min.js" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var packageTable = $("#myTables").DataTable({
        "ajax": "../api/ajax/getTransactions.php",
        "order": [0,'desc'],
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bInfo" : false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [ 1,2,3,4,5],

        },{
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true,
        }]
    });
    function removeTransaction(id){
        swal({
            title: "WARNING!",
            text: "You're about to remove a transaction",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete)
            {
                confirmRemove(id);
            }
        });
    };
    function confirmRemove(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data:{
                id: id,
            },
            url: "admin-transaction-delete.php",
            success: function(response){
                console.log("success");
                var productTable=$("#myTables").DataTable();
                productTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

I do not know where is the problem here.

Comment: How are you calling `removeTransaction()` ?  What does "not prompting *itself*" mean?  Do you mean "not showing"?  In which case refer to first question.

Comment: I am calling `removeTransaction()` using this line of code `<a onclick="removeTransaction(' . $data['id'] . ')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' which works the way I need it. the problem is that it's not displaying the alert itself.

Comment: Are you saying removeTransaction() is removing transaction but not calling the sweetalert to confirm? completely bypassing the confirmation?

Comment: yes, that's what it is @NawedKhan